In Next.js, how should I display an error for a particular component without blocking the entire page?
In Next.js, how should I display an error for a particular component without blocking the entire page, showing the error only for that component while allowing the rest of the components to function normally?
import CardWrapper from '@/app/ui/dashboard/cards';
import RevenueChart from '@/app/ui/dashboard/revenue-chart';
import LatestInvoices from '@/app/ui/dashboard/latest-invoices';
import { lusitana } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { CardsSkeleton, LatestInvoicesSkeleton, RevenueChartSkeleton } from '@/app/ui/skeletons';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'next/dist/client/components/error-boundary';

export default async function Page() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl`}>
        Dashboard
      </h1>
      <div className="grid gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
      <Suspense fallback={<CardsSkeleton />}>
          <CardWrapper />
      </Suspense>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-8">
        <Suspense fallback={<RevenueChartSkeleton />}>
          <RevenueChart />
        </Suspense>
        <Suspense fallback={<LatestInvoicesSkeleton/>}>
        <LatestInvoices/>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}


Let's imagine an unknown error occurs in the  component. I want to display an error message for this component only, while allowing the rest of the components to display their data.
RevenueChart component

import { generateYAxis } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { CalendarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { lusitana } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import { Revenue } from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import { fetchRevenue } from '@/app/lib/data';



export default async function RevenueChart() {

  const revenue = await fetchRevenue();

  const chartHeight = 350;
  
  const { yAxisLabels, topLabel } = generateYAxis(revenue||[]);

  
  

  if (!revenue || revenue.length === 0) {
    return <p className="mt-4 text-gray-400">No data available.</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full md:col-span-4">
      <h2 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl`}>
        Recent Revenue
      </h2>
      
      <div className="rounded-xl bg-gray-50 p-4">
        <div className="sm:grid-cols-13 mt-0 grid grid-cols-12 items-end gap-2 rounded-md bg-white p-4 md:gap-4">
          <div
            className="mb-6 hidden flex-col justify-between text-sm text-gray-400 sm:flex"
            style={{ height: `${chartHeight}px` }}
          >
            {yAxisLabels.map((label) => (
              <p key={label}>{label}</p>
            ))}
          </div>

          {revenue.map((month) => (
            <div key={month.month} className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2 ">
              <div
                className="w-full rounded-md bg-blue-300"
                style={{
                  height: `${(chartHeight / topLabel) * month.revenue}px`,
                }}
              ></div>
              <p className="-rotate-90 text-sm text-gray-400 sm:rotate-0">
                {month.month}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
          
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center pb-2 pt-6">
          <CalendarIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-500" />
          <h3 className="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-500 ">Last 12 months</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


What is the solution for it?
